# does PHP 5.3 change the way file_get_contents works?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm having an odd issue with PHP's `file_get_contents`.

In the past, `file_get_contents` on a remote file returns the text of that file regardless of the HTTP status code returned. If I hit an API and it sends back JSON error information with a status of 500, `file_get_contents` gives me that JSON (with no indication that an error code was encountered).

I've just set up a Ubuntu 10.04 server, which is the first Ubuntu to have PHP 5.3. Instead of giving me the JSON, PHP throws a warning when a 500 error is present. As a result, I can't parse the JSON and give a nice error message.

It's nice that PHP is noticing there's an error in the remote file, but I **need** the JSON even (especially!) if there's a 500 error. There doesn't appear to be any way to switch this off. Has anyone encountered this? Any tips?

Comment: I'm confused - warnings don't stop execution so I don't see why you "can't parse the JSON".  What is the var_dump of the data you DO receive back?

Comment: `var_dump` of the return is empty, that's the issue. The JSON is never returned.

Comment: Sounds like there's a change with the fopen wrappers and not file_get_contents itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell PHP to ignore stream errors when using `file_get_contents` by providing an appropriate stream context (using [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/stream_context_create)) with the `ignore_errors` option set to `true`.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('ignore_errors'=>true)));
$contents = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
```

You could also peek at `$http_response_header` for the response headers, including the status code.

Comment: Cheers for the `$http_response_header` tip. I can’t believe this isn’t properly documented on php.net!

Comment: @Mathias, what would you suggest to improve the documentation? A "see also" link to `$http_response_header`?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Currently, the *only* reference to `$http_response_header` on the doc page for `file_get_contents` is some guy’s comment. Would be great if you could make it more clear somehow :)

Comment: @Mathias, I added a link in the "see also" section of [`file_get_contents`](http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents) to the page describing `$http_response_header`.

Comment: @salathe: In the name of every PHP noob (like me) who visits that page from now on: thank you!